# Why the extruder is making this noise? CR10 Smart Pro

Tags: extruder, extrusion, creality-cr-10, creality

The extruder makes a weird sound like moving an old door without an oily hinge - both when advancing or retracting.

This video shows the problem:

https://www.veed.io/view/055d1724-838a-48d1-98d7-8eaf3076ea2b?panel=share

I did everything, but the noise was still there.

Everything seems OK. I am trying to figure out what I should do. I took pictures from inside the extruder and shared them below.

[image]
[image]
[image]
[image]
[image]

Comment: What kind of sound? Can you describe it? Is it only when advancing? Retracting? Both?

Comment: @Davo Thanks for your reply. I recorded a video and shared the link in the question. Both of them, It makes a weird sound like moving an old door without an oily hinge.

Comment: The video does not appear to load for some reason on my browser. If you put the video on youtube, you can then embed the video into your question, which would make it easier for people to view, and then possibly provide you with a solution.

Comment: Has it always made the sound? If not, what caused the sound to start? What actions may have caused it to start? You say that you've tried "everything" - could you list what those things are, to save people suggesting things that you've already tried. Have to tried loosening, or tightening the screw? Oil is probably not a good idea as that can damage filament (see [Is lubricating filament a good idea?](https://3dprinting.stackexchange.com/q/7228/4762)). Please [edit] your question and put any additional info there and not in the comments.